# Real-time timer on wamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, wamp, hosting

i want to make a real-time timer, that is controlled from one browser/page, but is displayed on multiple pages. I have the function for the timer and I found a thing called Node.js and tried to set it up. But it creates a server on port 3000. As I understand I get 2 servers. How could i set up node.js on wamp server?

Answer (score 0):

You can proxy requests that get to your WAMP to your Node app if you want both of them running. Then Node app can then be visible as a subdirectory on your main server.

Here is an example on how to do this not for a Node app but for a Ruby app, but it's also running on port 3000 and the idea is the same:

- [How to setup Rails on WAMP server using HTTP Proxy module?](http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-rails-on-wamp-server-using-http-proxy-module.html)